# Python memcache consistent hashing using ketama

Tags: python, memcached, consistent-hashing

I have a code which add extra memcache instance at run time, but this makes my keys lost. I know there are several libraries available like consistent_hash, hash_ring but I am unable to use them in my code. I know there is ketama available but couldn't find python code sample for it.

```
import random
import string
import memcache


class MemcacheClient(memcache.Client):
    """ A memcache subclass. It currently allows you to add a new host at run
    time. 

    Sadly, this truely messes with the our keys. I.E. Adding a host at runtime
    effectively wipes our cache all together...Wonder why?
    """

    def _get_server(self, key):
        """ Current implementation of Memcache client
        """
        return super(MemcacheClient, self)._get_server(key)

    def add_server(self, server):
        """ Adds a host at runtime to client
        """
        # Create a new host entry
        server = memcache._Host(
            server, self.debug, dead_retry=self.dead_retry,
            socket_timeout=self.socket_timeout,
            flush_on_reconnect=self.flush_on_reconnect
        )
        # Add this to our server choices 
        self.servers.append(server)
        # Update our buckets
        self.buckets.append(server)


def random_key(size):
    """ Generates a random key
    """
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(size))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We have 7 running memcached servers
    servers = ['127.0.0.1:1121%d' % i for i in range(1,8)]
    # We have 100 keys to split across our servers
    keys = [random_key(10) for i in range(100)]
    # Init our subclass
    client = MemcacheClient(servers=servers)
    # Distribute the keys on our servers
    for key in keys:
        client.set(key, 1)

    # Check how many keys come back 
    valid_keys = client.get_multi(keys)
    print '%s percent of keys matched' % ((len(valid_keys)/float(len(keys))) * 100)

    # We add another server...and pow!
    client.add_server('127.0.0.1:11219')
    print 'Added new server' 

    valid_keys = client.get_multi(keys)
    print '%s percent of keys stil matched' % ((len(valid_keys)/float(len(keys))) * 100)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, basically you have to override the _get _server() method to change the server distribution algorithm.

I've done some searching over the internet and found this article on google, [amix.dk/blog/post/19367](http://amix.dk/blog/post/19367), which is a very good material written by Amir Salihefendic, that helps a lot to understand how the ketama consistent hash algorithm works, and also has a ketama implementation on a Python class called HashRing made by him.

So I basically used his class and changed it a little to fit Memcached client needs. The modifications were the change of the md5 module that was depprecated, and the change of the string used to generate the keys for the servers from:

```
key = self.gen_key('%s:%s' % (node, i))
```

to:

```
key = self.gen_key(
          '%s:%s:%s:%s' % (node.address[0],
          node.address[1], i, node.weight)
      )
```

I also fixed a bug that caused an infinite loop on get_nodes() method when the algorithm didn't find a server at the first loop.

The old get_nodes() method (will enter infinite loop if no server is yielded).

```
def get_nodes(self, string_key):
    """Given a string key it returns the nodes as a generator that can hold the key.

    The generator is never ending and iterates through the ring
    starting at the correct position.
    """
    if not self.ring:
        yield None, None

    node, pos = self.get_node_pos(string_key)
    for key in self._sorted_keys[pos:]:
        yield self.ring[key]

    while True:
        for key in self._sorted_keys:
            yield self.ring[key]
```

The new get_nodes() method:

```
def get_nodes(self, string_key):
    if not self.ring:
        yield None, None

    node, pos = self.get_node_pos(string_key)
    for key in self._sorted_keys[pos:]:
        if key in self.ring:
            yield self.ring[key]

    for key in self._sorted_keys[:pos]:
        if key in self.ring:
            yield self.ring[key]
```

I've added a new forloop scope on add_node() as well as on remove_node() method to consider the weight of the server for adding more replicas.

Old way:

```
for i in xrange(0, self.replicas):
    key = self.gen_key('%s:%s' % (node, i))
    self.ring[key] = node
    self._sorted_keys.append(key)
```

New way:

```
for i in xrange(0, self.replicas):
    for x in range(0, node.weight):
        key = self.gen_key(
            '%s:%s:%s:%s' % (node.address[0],
            node.address[1], i, node.weight)
        )

        if key not in self.ring:
            self.ring[key] = node
            self._sorted_keys.append(key)
```

The above code regards to the add_node() method, but the some idea applies to remove_node().

Well, maybe there are some other changes I've made, I just don't recall any other for now. This is the suited HashRing class:

```
from hashlib import md5    
class HashRing(object):

    def __init__(self, nodes=None, replicas=3):
        """Manages a hash ring.

        `nodes` is a list of objects that have a proper __str__ representation.
        `replicas` indicates how many virtual points should be used pr. node,
        replicas are required to improve the distribution.
        """
        self.replicas = replicas

        self.ring = dict()
        self._sorted_keys = []

        if nodes:
            for node in nodes:
                self.add_node(node)

    def add_node(self, node):
        """Adds a `node` to the hash ring (including a number of replicas).
        """
        for i in xrange(0, self.replicas):
            """This will ensure that a server with a bigger weight will have
            more copies into the ring increasing it's probability to be retrieved.
            """
            for x in range(0, node.weight):
                key = self.gen_key(
                    '%s:%s:%s:%s' % (node.address[0],
                    node.address[1], i, node.weight)
                )

                if key not in self.ring:
                    self.ring[key] = node
                    self._sorted_keys.append(key)

        self._sorted_keys.sort()

    def remove_node(self, node):
        """Removes `node` from the hash ring and its replicas.
        """
        for i in xrange(0, self.replicas):
            for x in range(node.weight):
                key = self.gen_key(
                    '%s:%s:%s:%s' % (node.address[0],
                    node.address[1], i, node.weight)
                )

                if key in self.ring:
                    del self.ring[key]
                    self._sorted_keys.remove(key)

    def get_node(self, string_key):
        """
        Given a string key a corresponding node in the hash ring is returned.

        If the hash ring is empty, `None` is returned.
        """
        return self.get_node_pos(string_key)[0]

    def get_node_pos(self, string_key):
        """Given a string key a corresponding node in the hash ring is returned
        along with it's position in the ring.

        If the hash ring is empty, (`None`, `None`) is returned.
        """
        if not self.ring:
            return None, None

        key = self.gen_key(string_key)

        nodes = self._sorted_keys
        for i in xrange(0, len(nodes)):
            node = nodes[i]
            if key <= node:
                return self.ring[node], i

        return self.ring[nodes[0]], 0

    def get_nodes(self, string_key):
        """Given a string key it returns the nodes as a generator that can hold
        the key.

        The generator is never ending and iterates through the ring
        starting at the correct position.
        """
        if not self.ring:
            yield None, None

        node, pos = self.get_node_pos(string_key)
        for key in self._sorted_keys[pos:]:
            if key in self.ring:
                yield self.ring[key]

        for key in self._sorted_keys[:pos]:
            if key in self.ring:
                yield self.ring[key]

    @staticmethod
    def gen_key(key):
        """Given a string key it returns a long value,
        this long value represents a place on the hash ring.

        md5 is currently used because it mixes well.
        """
        m = md5()
        m.update(key)
        return long(m.hexdigest(), 16)
```

I changed your class a little in order to make it more flexible for deciding when to use ketama algorithm, or the default - modulo.

I noticed that when writing your add_server() method you forgot to consider the weight of the server when appending it to the buckets list.

So this is how the new MemcacheClient would look like:

```
from consistent_hash import HashRing


class MemcacheClient(memcache.Client):
    """ A memcache subclass. It currently allows you to add a new host at run
    time.
    """
    available_algorithms = ['ketama', 'modulo']
    hash_algorithm_index = 0

    def __init__(self, hash_algorithm='ketama', *args, **kwargs):
        super(MemcacheClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if hash_algorithm in self.available_algorithms:
            self.hash_algorithm_index = self.available_algorithms.index(
                hash_algorithm)

            if hash_algorithm == 'ketama':
                self.consistent_hash_manager = HashRing(nodes=self.servers)
            else:
                self.consistent_hash_manager = None
        else:
            raise Exception(
                "The algorithm \"%s\" is not implemented for this client. The "
                "options are \"%s\""
                "" % (hash_algorithm, " or ".join(self.available_algorithms))
            )

    def _get_server(self, key):
        """ Returns the most likely server to hold the key
        """

        if self.hash_algorithm  == 'ketama':
            """ Basic concept of the Implementation of ketama algorithm
            e.g. ring = {100:server1, 110:server2, 120:server3, 140:server4}
            If the hash of the current key is 105, it server will be the next
            bigger integer in the ring which is 110 (server2)
            If a server is added on position 108 the key will be now allocated
            to it and not to server 110. Otherwise if the server on position
            110 is removed the key will now belong to de server 120.
            If there's no bigger integer position in the ring then the hash of
            the key, it will take the first server from the ring.
            """
            # The variable "servers" is the list of the servers in the ring
            # starting from the next bigger integer to the hash of the key,
            # till it finds the one that holds the key
            servers_generator = self.consistent_hash_manager.get_nodes(key)
            for server in servers_generator:
                if server.connect():
                    #print server.address[1]
                    return server, key
            return None, None

        else:
            return super(MemcacheClient, self)._get_server(key)

    def add_server(self, server):
        """ Adds a host at runtime to client
        """

        # Uncomment this to protect the Client from adding a server in case
        # there's no reliable consistent hash algorithm such as MODULO
        """
        if not self.consistent_hash_manager:
            raise Exception("The current consistent hash algorithm (\"%s\") is"
                            " not reliable for adding a new server"
                            "" % self.hash_algorithm)
        """

        # Create a new host entry
        server = memcache._Host(
            server, self.debug, dead_retry=self.dead_retry,
            socket_timeout=self.socket_timeout,
            flush_on_reconnect=self.flush_on_reconnect
        )
        # Add this to our server choices 
        self.servers.append(server)

        """This for statement will ensure that a server with a bigger weight
        will have more copies into the buckets increasing it's probability to
        be retrieved.
        """
        for i in range(server.weight):
            self.buckets.append(server)

        # Adds this node to the circle
        if self.consistent_hash_manager:
            self.consistent_hash_manager.add_node(server)

def random_key(size):
    """ Generates a random key
    """
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.letters) for _ in range(size))


def run_consistent_hash_test(client_obj):
    # We have 500 keys to split across our servers
    keys = [random_key(100) for i in range(500)]

    print(
        "\n/////////// CONSISTENT HASH ALGORITHM \"%s\" //////////////"
        "" % client_obj.hash_algorithm.upper()
    )

    print("\n->These are the %s servers:" % len(client_obj.servers))
    str_servers = ""
    for server in client_obj.servers:
        str_servers += "%s:%s, " % (server.address[0], server.address[1])
    print("******************************************************************")
    print(str_servers)
    print("******************************************************************")

    # Clear all previous keys from memcache
    client_obj.flush_all()

    # Distribute the keys over the servers
    for key in keys:
        client_obj.set(key, 1)

    print(
        "\n%d keys distributed for %d server(s)\n"
        "" % (len(keys), len(client_obj.servers))
    )

    # Check how many keys come back
    valid_keys = client_obj.get_multi(keys)
    print(
        "%s percent of keys matched, before adding extra servers.\n" \
        "" %((len(valid_keys) / float(len(keys))) * 100)
    )

    # Add 5 new extra servers
    interval_extra_servers = range(19, 24)
    extra_servers = ['127.0.0.1:112%d' % i for i in interval_extra_servers]
    for server in extra_servers:
        client_obj.add_server(server)

    # Check how many keys come back after adding the extra servers
    valid_keys = client_obj.get_multi(keys)
    print (
        "Added %d new server(s).\n%s percent of keys still matched" \
        "" % (len(interval_extra_servers),
        (len(valid_keys) / float(len(keys))) * 100)
    )

    print("\n***************************************************************"
          "****\n")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # We have 8 running memcached servers
    interval_servers = range(11, 19)
    servers = ['127.0.0.1:112%d' % i for i in interval_servers]
    """
    Init our subclass. The hash_algorithm paramether can be "modulo"<-
    (default) or "ketama" (the new one).
    """
    client = MemcacheClient(servers=servers, hash_algorithm='ketama')
    run_consistent_hash_test(client)
```

If you run this class directly on terminal it will show a proper output

Comment: Here in my github I've created a simple test to excecute the implementation above: [link to my github](https://github.com/mau21mau/python-ketama)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me...before creating a new host entry, add a condition. if server is None, then execute server=memcahce. line

Answer (score 0):

I know it's too late to answer this question, but I'm hoping it will be helpful for some. I have the working class that you can use directly. This will be a drop in replacement for the original `memcache.Client`.

```
class KetamaMemcacheClient(memcache.Client):
    """
    This memcache client implements consistent hashing algorithm "ketama".

    This will make sure that the cache miss happening while adding or removing
    a node from the client to very minimal.
    """

    #
    # Server weight means, numer of slots given for one server. For better
    # performence it whould be between 100-200 - Adjust the weight to see how
    # cache miss changing.
    #
    DEFAULT_SERVER_WEIGHT = 200

    # Total number of slots on the ring.
    # If addition or deltion of a new node only causes 1 to 5 percentage cache
    # miss on the current configuraiton. ie; K / RING_SIZE - where K means total
    # keys.
    RING_SIZE = 2 ** 16

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        Add some special parameters to handle the servers allocation.
        """
        # Mapping between ring slot -> server.
        self._ketama_server_ring = {}

        # Sorted server slots on top of the virtual ring.
        self._ketama_server_slots = []

        super(KetamaMemcacheClient, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def _get_server(self, key):
        """
        Get the memcache server corresponding to the given key.
        :param key: The input query.

        :return: A tuple with (server_obj, key).
        """
        # map the key on to the ring slot space.
        h_key = self._generate_ring_slot(key)

        for slot in self._ketama_server_slots:
            if h_key <= slot:
                server = self._ketama_server_ring[slot]
                if server.connect():
                    return (server, key)

        # Even after allocating the server, if the h_key won't fit
        # on any server, then pick the first server on the ring.
        server = self._ketama_server_ring[self._ketama_server_slots[0]] if \
                self._ketama_server_slots else None

        server and server.connect()

        return server, key

    def add_server(self, server):
        """
        Add new server to the client.

        :param servers: server host in <IP>:<PORT> format.
                        or in tuple of (<IP>:<PORT>, weight)
        """
        server_obj = memcache._Host(
            server if isinstance(server, tuple) else (
                server, self.DEFAULT_SERVER_WEIGHT),
            self.debug, dead_retry=self.dead_retry,
            socket_timeout=self.socket_timeout,
            flush_on_reconnect=self.flush_on_reconnect)

        self._place_server_on_ring(server_obj)

    def set_servers(self, servers):
        """
        Add a pool of servers into the client.

        :param servers: List of server hosts in <IP>:<PORT> format.
                        or
                        List of tuples with each tuple of the format
                        (<IP>:<PORT>, weight)
        """
        # Set the default weight if weight isn't passed.
        self.servers = [memcache._Host(
            s if isinstance(s, tuple) else (s, self.DEFAULT_SERVER_WEIGHT),
            self.debug, dead_retry=self.dead_retry,
            socket_timeout=self.socket_timeout,
            flush_on_reconnect=self.flush_on_reconnect) for s in servers]

        # Place all the servers on rings based on the slot allocation
        # specifications.
        [self._place_server_on_ring(s) for s in self.servers]

    def _place_server_on_ring(self, server):
        """
        Place given server on the ring.
        :param server: An instance of :class:~`memcache._Host`.
        """
        server_slots = self._get_server_slots_on_ring(server)
        for slot in server_slots:
            if slot not in self._ketama_server_ring:
                self._ketama_server_ring[slot] = server
                self._ketama_server_slots.append(slot)
            else:
                # There is a key collection(<<<1% chance).
                # Discarding this scenario now.
                # TODO: Handle it.
                pass

        # Append the sorted server slot list
        self._ketama_server_slots.sort()

    def _get_server_slots_on_ring(self, server):
        """
        Returns list of slot on the ring for given server.

        This make sure that the slots won't collid with others server.
        :param server: An object of :class:~`memcache._Host`.

        :return: list of slots on the ring.
        """
        server_slots = []

        for i in range(0, server.weight):
            server_key = "{}_{}".format("{}:{}".format(server.ip,
                                                       server.port), i)

            server_slots.append(self._generate_ring_slot(server_key))

        return server_slots

    def _generate_ring_slot(self, key):
        """
        Hash function which give random slots on the ring. Hash functon make
        sure that the key distribution is even as much as possible.

        :param key: Key which need to be mapped to the hash space.
        :type key: str

        :return: hash key corresponding to `key`
        """
        # Simple hash method using python's internal hash algorithm.
        #h_key = hash(key) & 0xffff

        # crc32 based hashing
        #h_key = ((crc32(key) & 0xffffffff) >> 16) & 0xffff

        # For better randomness
        h_key = ((crc32(key) & 0xffffffff)) & 0xffff

        return h_key


client = KetamaMemcacheClient(servers)
# This change in number of servers only affect very few key misses.
client.add_server('127.0.0.1:11218')
```

I haven't added `remove_server` method to remove some dead server from the configured server list. That is pretty easy by keeping a inverted server mapping and remove the slots allocated to that server.

Enjoy !